# How to set window's owner to MainWindow through XAML in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, owner

How can I set window's owner to `Application.Current.MainWindow` through XAML?
So far I've tried this:

```
<Window x:Class="ModalWindow.CustomModalWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Owner="System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow">
<!--Some XAML code-->
</Window>
```

That didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to set Window.Owner ?
What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Owner="System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow"` won't work because "System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow" is just a string

`Window.Owner` isn't a dependency property, so binding to static source (`"{Binding Path=MainWindow, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"`) won't work also

I modified `App` class like this:

```
namespace WpfDemos
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static Window CurrentMainWindow
        {
            get { return Current.MainWindow; }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in my window referenced that property via `{x:Static}` extension:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDemos.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfDemos="clr-namespace:WpfDemos"
        Owner="{x:Static wpfDemos:App.CurrentMainWindow}"
```

so it is possible, but why?

Comment: Why so much work, when you just can add it to the code. see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004247/2289942

Comment: I am creating a custom modal dialog window and would like to set its owner to MainWindow, I thought I would do it in XAML instead of the code behind so it would be more elegant, but seemingly there is no straightforward solution because I will have to modify `App.xaml.cs` in that case.

Comment: `App` class is very often modified or extended to perform initialization when application is launched. Adding a property is also completely acceptable