# Child WPF on top of parent WPF (MvvmCross)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross, .net-5

I would like to open a new WPF window on top of the parent window, or at least where the mouse is.
I can receive the correct mouse coordinates, but it does not update the Left and Top attribute correctly, means no effect but it works when I use hard-coded coordinates

```
this.Left = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(null).X;
this.Top = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(null).Y;
```

So I try to use WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" in the WPF, but I do not know how to set the parent WPF in MvvmCross.
I call the child window like this by the parent ViewModel:

```
ShowChildCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await NavigationService.Navigate<ChildViewModel>());
```

but it does not supply any option to set a parent. My child WPF class looks this:

```
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Presenters.Attributes;

namespace test.wpf.Views
{
    [MvxWindowPresentation(Identifier = nameof(ChildView), Modal = false)]
    public partial class GroupMembershipView
    {
        public ChildView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

}
```

Besides I tried to figure out how to set it maybe in WPF itself:

```
Owner="{x:Static test.wpf:App.CurrentMainWindow}
```

But no success.
What is the correct way to define the parent, or just set the new WPF window on top in MvvmCross?

Comment: I'm not experienced with this MvvmCross, but - are you navigating to a different window or creating a popup (a new one) ? From your command it looks like navigation. If you want to pop a new window, I would use the messenger service to send a message to the owner and pop from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I missed something one following post: [How to set window's owner to MainWindow through XAML in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004154/how-to-set-windows-owner-to-mainwindow-through-xaml-in-wpf/48004247#48004247)

so, I added the mentioned function to my App.xaml.cs

```
public static MvxWindow CurrentMainWindow
{
    get { return (MvxWindow)Current.MainWindow; }
}
```

and in the WPF like mentioned in the post:

```
xmlns:test.wpf="clr-namespace:test.wpf"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Owner="{x:Static test.wpf:App.CurrentMainWindow}"
```